# How can we get data of current logged in user in flutter if used django as a backend

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

I want to show widgets in flutter as per the types of user logged in. For example if the user is logged in as seller, he/she can see widgets to sell the goods and if he/she is buyer they should get option to buy goods. I want to achieve this in flutter with django backend...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must return a role with the user object.

as example the rules are

```
"role":1
```

for saler

```
"role":2
```

for buyer

```
"role":3
```

for viewer

an so on

then use your state management solution for flutter to check the role of current logged in user